# How do i sort a view panel using the ftsearch method to sort like the view?

Tags: xpages

I see 8.5.3 has ftsearchSorted but can you use that in the search parameter in a viewpanel?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a sort column on the view data source you should get the results back sorted