# Use ftsearch in a view control along with a sorted column

Tags: full-text-search, xpages

I use the search parameter of a view control to perform full text search, but I want to get the results sorted according to a certain column that is sorted as descending in the corresponding view. I followed the steps of the above relevant question:

[How do i sort a view panel using the ftsearch method to sort like the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815386/how-do-i-sort-a-view-panel-using-the-ftsearch-method-to-sort-like-the-view)

So, although I selected the correct column for the sortColumn parameter and descending order for the sortOrder parameter, the following exception occurs:

```
The design of column F_Estate_AAA does not provide for sorting the view as requested.

com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: The design of column F_Estate_AAA does not provide for sorting the view as requested.
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.readEntries(AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.java:95)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntryArray.readEntries(DominoViewEntryArray.java:104)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.readViewEntries(DominoViewDataContainer.java:548)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.getRowCount(DominoViewDataContainer.java:527)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel.getRowCount(DominoViewDataModel.java:109)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:76)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:71)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager.createPagerState(UIPager.java:540)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.XPagerRenderer.encodeChildren(XPagerRenderer.java:61)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.processPagerCell(ViewPanelRenderer.java:656)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.encodeBegin(ViewPanelRenderer.java:354)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:788)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(UIDataEx.java:413)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewPanel.encodeBegin(UIViewPanel.java:288)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:209)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

NotesException: The design of column F_Estate_AAA does not provide for sorting the view as requested.
lotus.domino.local.View.NFTSearchSorted(Native Method)
lotus.domino.local.View.FTSearchSorted(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.FTViewNavigatorEx.createCollection(FTViewNavigatorEx.java:79)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.readEntries(AbstractViewCollectionNavigator.java:76)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntryArray.readEntries(DominoViewEntryArray.java:104)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.readViewEntries(DominoViewDataContainer.java:548)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataContainer.getRowCount(DominoViewDataContainer.java:527)
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewDataModel.getRowCount(DominoViewDataModel.java:109)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:76)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager$PagerState.<init>(UIPager.java:71)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIPager.createPagerState(UIPager.java:540)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.XPagerRenderer.encodeChildren(XPagerRenderer.java:61)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.processPagerCell(ViewPanelRenderer.java:656)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.ViewPanelRenderer.encodeBegin(ViewPanelRenderer.java:354)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:788)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataEx.encodeBegin(UIDataEx.java:413)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewPanel.encodeBegin(UIViewPanel.java:288)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:840)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:871)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:851)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:641)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:335)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:209)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

If I remove the sortColumn and sortOrder parameters, there is no exception, but of course the results are not sorted like in the corresponding view.

Is there something missing from the steps? Can anyone tell me any possible reason for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the column 'F_Estate_AAA' allow for column sorting in the view?

Comment: The column holds a text field which stores a code of digits. When I open the view from client I can see the documents in descending or ascending order. Is this what you mean? Or do I need to check something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the column is marked as "sorted" and that you checked the sort option when clicking on the header. You might want to be careful with your approach. There is exactly ONE FT Index per database. So a view.ftsearch actually does a ftsearch in the database (which is fast) and then compares all the hits to the documents in the view (if you have a lot, that is creepy slow, even if you only show the first 20 hits).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this setting for the column. No exception occurs now and it works as expected. However, probably I have to consider your comments concerning the FT Search approach.